# How to check if NTPD updates machine's time successfully using shell?

Tags: time, ntpd

I'm trying to use NTPD to update my Linux machine's time to a specified NTP server.
Here is the scenario:

Each time the Linux machine starts up, I want to update the time from NTP server and **if it's not successful, I want to try again every 5 minutes until successfully** (max is 2 hours).

I searched around and find that I should(?) use NTPD and use some command like:

`#ntpdate  ntp.server.com` (before starting NTPD)
`#ntpd some_options_to_start`

The questions are:

1. How can I know if the time was successfully updated by these commands?
2. Can I set the interval to update time from ntpd? (or I have to use something like `sleep` and loop with `do`..`while`/`for` in shell?)

Note that I want to execute the above commands in a shell script and will put the shell in  a web server. Then clients (with a web browser browser) will execute the script on the website.  So I need to check if the update is successful or not to send result to the client (over the web).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using a script to monitor `ntpd` is not commonly done.  Usually a monitoring tool like `nagios` or `munin` is used to monitor the daemon.  The tool can send you an alert when things go wrong.  I have `munin` emailing me if the offset exceeds 15 milliseconds.

Normally, you should use an odd number of servers so that the daemon can perform an election among the servers if one goes off.  Three is usually adequate, and more than five is excessive.  Clients on your internal network should be able to get by with one internal server if you monitor it.  Use legitimate servers or your ISPs NTP or DNS servers as clock sources.  There are public pools as well as public servers.

`ntpd` is self tuning and you should not need to adjust it once it is configured and started.  With recent `ntpd` implementations you can drop use of `ntpdate` entirely as they can do the initial setting of the date.

The following script will parse the offsets in the output of ntpd and report an excessive offset.  You could run it from cron to email you if there are problems.  The script defaults to alerting on an offset of 0.1 seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash
limit=100   # Set your limit in milliseconds here
offsets=$(ntpq -nc peers | tail -n +3 | cut -c 62-66 | tr -d '-')
for offset in ${offsets}; do
    if [ ${offset:-0} -ge ${limit:-100} ]; then
        echo "An NTPD offset is excessive - Please investigate"
        exit 1  
    fi  
done
# EOF
```

Comment: This is the first instance I've heard of anyone monitoring system time.  Excellent answer.

Comment: @BruceEdiger I take it you have never heard of the folks on the time-nuts mailing list.

Comment: As far as "Using a script to monitor ntpd is not commonly done" goes; the scripts directory inside of the ntp tarball points to the opposite conclusion.

Comment: @dvc The scripts there don't seem to include the requested functionality.  There seems to be some code to generate SNMP traps, but I haven't encountered SNMP to monitor NTP.  I've had to do my own monitoring in several large organizations.

Comment: And if depending on *exact number of lines and characters* in the output is not your thing, you can run the command as `ntpq -nc peers | sed '1,/^====/d' | awk '{print $9}' | cut -d. -f1 | tr -d -` instead.

Answer (score 9):

To answer the first question, `ntpdate` usually tells you what it did, or maybe did not do.

```
[root@flask rc.d]# ntpdate dagoo
12 Aug 10:04:03 ntpdate[20585]: adjust time server 10.0.0.15 offset -0.042285 sec
```

The NTP daemon, `ntpd`, runs constantly, and asks NTP servers (usually configured in `/etc/ntp.conf`) for the time every so often.  You shouldn't have to run your script every 5 minutes. `ntpdate` should bring the machine into near synch with the server, and `ntpd` will run in the background and keep it in synch. You don't set the interval that ntpd tries, it adjusts the interval based on how it perceives the local clock drifts from the servers, and the quality of the connections to the servers.

You can use a program named `ntpdc` to see what `ntpd` keeps as information:

```
1 % ntpdc 
ntpdc> peers
     remote           local      st poll reach  delay   offset    disp
=======================================================================
*min-time-01.ine 10.0.0.15        1 1024  377 0.07047  0.014673 0.14360
=dns-01.esd189.o 10.0.0.15        2 1024  377 0.07587  0.022277 0.13660
ntpdc>
```

I think that the number you typically have an interest in is "offset", that's the number of seconds your local clock is off from the server's clock.

As the `man` page for `ntpdc` states for the "peers" command :

```
the current estimated delay, offset and dispersion of the peer, all in seconds.
```

So, clearly, the "offset" is in seconds.

It appears that `ntpdc` is deprecated, replaced by `ntpq`. `ntpq` has a "peers" interactive command, that does give "offset" in milliseconds. My Redhat server has both `ntpdc` and `ntpq`, so you'll need to be careful.

Comment: Great! But there is an unclear part in my question. I 'm going to execute a shell script in a C program. And wanted to check the return value (maybe I'll use the system("shellscript") function). Your answer gives me an idea that we should not set interval for NTPD and just in case, I want to change NTP server, I have to edit ntp.conf file. Could you tell me the way ntpd works with ntp server. Do I have to restart ntpd daemon after editing ntp.conf file (again using **shell script**)

Comment: ntpd is a daemon process - it runs continuously.  It decides how often to ask a server for current time, and how often and how much to change the local clock, based on how the local clock drifts: you can't really control any of the intervals. ntpd runs in the background. To change an NTP server, you edit /etc/ntp.conf, and stop then start ntpd.

Comment: I should also mention that the code fragment you posted should get run at or above runlevel 3 during the boot.  ntpdate sets the system clock, then ntpd becomes a daemon process, and keeps the clock synched to the servers. Ordinarily, you don't run those 2 lines of code to just "set the clock".

Comment: I got it. How about ntpdate when it gets the wrong ntpserver ( for example) and don't work correctly. How can I know it from shell scripts?

Answer (score 8):

Use ntpstat.

```
myserver # ntpstat
synchronised to NTP server (10.89.160.13) at stratum 4
   time correct to within 124 ms
   polling server every 1024 s
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, I've found ntpstat buggy. After unplugging my network cable, it was still shown as synchronised with return status 0, although `ntpq -p` showed no peers. So I'm not trusting this utility.

Answer (score 7):

`ntp-wait` was made for this problem.

Five minutes with `man ntp-wait` and you should be up and running...

Comment: I found ntp-wait in debian, but not in centos. please help !

Answer (score 2):

Chrony is claimed to handle your use case better than NTPd (network and machine on/off, suspend, etc.). See

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ChronyDefaultNTP

RE why do I think chronny is good:
It came pre-installed on my fedora machine and I've never had any issue with it (used it for years now). I've never had issues with ntpd in the past as well but if you read on the link I have provided, there is some information as to why chrony is better for non-always on machines. That's why I suggested to the op to try it out, it may or may not work better for him. So it's just another good option to try before going into too much tuning, optimizing and hacking ntpd.

Comment: please comment if you downvote with your rational

Comment: Why do you think chrony is better?

Comment: @dfc, it came pre-installed on my fedora machine and I've never had any issue with it (used it for years now). I've never had issues with ntpd in the past as well but if you read on the link I have provided, there is some information as to why chrony is better for non-always on machines. That's why I suggested to the op to try it out, it may or may not  work better for him. So it's just another good option to try before going into too much tuning, optimizing and hacking ntpd.

Comment: Rather add this info on the Answer itself. It is valuable enough, and you just might get the vote reversed.

Comment: Given your answer doesn't match the actual question, in my opinion is it better suited to be a comment on the question.

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel, it's debatable. I may say that this is another approach op may take. People often ask how to do something that they think is a solution to their problem instead of asking exactly what the want to achieve. The question makes me think that op is mostly interesting in getting the time synced, not so much what tool is used.

Answer (score 2):

I added to the @BillTHor bash script also a check for the ntpdstat exit code > 0:

```
#!/bin/bash
ntpstat > /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "NTPD not synchronized - Please investigate"
        exit 1
fi
limit=1000   # Set your limit in milliseconds here
offsets=$(ntpq -nc peers | tail -n +3 | cut -c 62-66 | tr -d '-')
for offset in ${offsets}; do
    if [ ${offset:-0} -ge ${limit:-100} ]; then
        echo "An NTPD offset is excessive - Please investigate"
        exit 1
    fi
done
# EOF
```

[UPDATE] since the script using ntpq output was unuseful for larget offset (more than 4 digits of  offset) I tried a new version using only ntpstat:

```
#!/bin/bash
ntpstat > /dev/null
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "NTPD not synchronized - Please investigate"
        exit 1
fi
limit=1000   # Set your limit in milliseconds here
#offsets=$(ntpq -nc peers | tail -n +3 | cut -c 62-66 | tr -d '-')
#offsets=$(ntpq -nc peers | tail -n +3 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 9 | tr -d '-' |tr -d '.')
offsets=$(ntpstat | tail -n +2 | head -n 1 | cut -c 27- | tr -d ' ms')
for offset in ${offsets}; do
    if [ ${offset:-0} -ge ${limit:-100} ]; then
        echo "NTPD offset is excessive: ${offset:-0} [ms] > ${limit:-100} [ms] - Please investigate"
        exit 1
    fi
done
# EOF`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 2):

**NTP offset** can be obtained with the following UNIX pipeline:

```
/usr/sbin/ntpq -pn | /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN { offset=1000 } $1 ~ /^\*/ { offset=$9 } END { print offset }'
```

**NTP peer count** can be obtained with the following UNIX pipeline:

```
/usr/sbin/ntpq -pn | egrep -c '^\*|^\+'
```

For **NTP offet** we use:

- warning > 250ms
- critical > 500ms

For **NTP peer count** we use:

- no warning threshold
- critical < 1

Zabbix-ready NTP monitoring config (source: Joyent):

```
# NTP
UserParameter=ntp.offset,/usr/sbin/ntpq -pn | /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN { offset=1000 } $1 ~ /^\*/ { offset=$9 } END { print offset }'
UserParameter=ntp.peers,/usr/sbin/ntpq -pn | egrep -c '^\*|^\+'
```

Nagios-ready NTP monitoring plugins:

check_ntp_offset:

```
#!/bin/bash
# thresholds
thresh_warn=250
thresh_crit=500

# metric
ntp_offset=$(/usr/sbin/ntpq -pn | /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN { offset=1000 } $1 ~ /^\*/ { offset=$9 } END { print offset }')

# Exit codes
STATE_OK=0
STATE_WARNING=1
STATE_CRITICAL=2
STATE_UNKNOWN=3

if [[ ! "$ntp_offset" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
   # NTP offset could not be read successfully
   echo "NTP OFFSET UNKNOWN - $ntp_offset"
   exit $STATE_UNKNOWN
elif [[ "$ntp_offset" -gt "$thresh_crit" ]] ; then
   # NTP offset is higher than the critical threshold
   echo "NTP OFFSET CRITICAL - ${ntp_offset}ms (> ${thresh_crit}ms)"
   exit $STATE_CRITICAL
elif [[ "$ntp_offset" -gt "$thresh_warn" ]] ; then
   # NTP offset is higher than the warning threshold
   echo "NTP OFFSET WARNING - ${ntp_offset}ms (> ${thresh_warn}ms)"
   exit $STATE_WARNING
else
   # NTP offset is within thresholds
   echo "NTP OFFSET OK - ${ntp_offset}ms (< ${thresh_warn}ms)"
   exit $STATE_OK
fi
```

check_ntp_peers:

```
#!/bin/bash
# thresholds
thresh_warn=1
thresh_crit=1

# metric
ntp_peers=$(/usr/sbin/ntpq -pn | egrep -c '^\*|^\+')

# Exit codes
STATE_OK=0
STATE_WARNING=1
STATE_CRITICAL=2
STATE_UNKNOWN=3

if [[ ! "$ntp_peers" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
   # NTP peers could not be read successfully
   echo "NTP PEERS UNKNOWN - $ntp_peers"
   exit $STATE_UNKNOWN
elif [[ "$ntp_peers" -lt "$thresh_crit" ]] ; then
   # NTP peers is lower than the critical threshold
   echo "NTP PEERS CRITICAL - $ntp_peers (< $thresh_crit)"
   exit $STATE_CRITICAL
elif [[ "$ntp_peers" -lt "$thresh_warn" ]] ; then
   # NTP peers is lower than the warning threshold
   echo "NTP PEERS WARNING - $ntp_peers (< $thresh_warn)"
   exit $STATE_WARNING
else
   # NTP peers is within thresholds
   echo "NTP PEERS OK - $ntp_peers (> $thresh_warn)"
   exit $STATE_OK
fi
```

I really should let the warning and critical thresholds in the Nagios scripts be configurable with -w and -c. They're not really fully plugin-ready without that. Further guidance on that in a tutorial here: 
http://www.kernel-panic.it/openbsd/nagios/nagios6.html

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

limit=100   # Set your limit in milliseconds here

offsets=$(ntpq -nc peers | tail -n +3 | awk '{print $9 }' | tr -d '-')

for offset in ${offsets}; 
do

    if [ ${offset:-0} -ge ${limit:-100} ];
    then
        echo "An NTPD offset is excessive - Please investigate"

        exit 1

    fi  
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#set -x
NTPLIMIT=100   # Set your NTPLIMIT in milliseconds here
offsets=$(ntpq -nc peers | tail -3 | cut -c 62-66 | tr -d '-')
for offset in ${offsets}; do
    if [ ${offset:-0} -ge ${NTPLIMIT:-100} ]; then
        echo "An NTPd offset is excessive Please investigate" exit;
        else
                echo "NTP is within 0.1 second of time server"
                exit;
        fi
done
```

Same as the previous answer above, but with a slight modification as the previous command will run the if statement for as many offsets, i.e. if offset is 3 then it will print NTP is within 0.1.... 3 times before closing. Could be annoying if you have a server that is a long way out of sync. There is probably a way to remove the for loop as well...